# problem using pointer array?

Tags: c, pointers

code:

```
char *m[10];
char * s;

int lcounter=0;
int sd=0;
char mem_buf [ 500 ];
while ( fgets ( mem_buf, sizeof mem_buf, infile ) != NULL )
{

    m[lcounter] =(char *) malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    item = strtok(mem_buf,delims);
    m[lcounter]=item;
    printf("\n value inside==== :%s:",m[lcounter]);
    lcounter=lcounter+1;

}

for(i=0;i<lcounter;i++)
{
    printf("\n value outside==== :%s:",m[sd]);
    sd++;
}
```

input:

```
goo|
bbb|
ccc|
```

When I execute this am getting below output:

```
value inside==== : goo
value inside==== : bbb
value inside==== : ccc

value outside====:ccc
value outside====:ccc
value outside====:ccc
```

But I need like:

```
value outside====:goo
value outside====:bbb
value outside====:ccc
```

Comment: @stefan Your comment doesn't make any sense. The culprit is `m[lcounter]=item`.

Comment: @chrisaycock: You are right :) I will remove it, i missed the strtok ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strcpy` if you want it to last outside of the loop.  `strtok` may reuse the same pointer.

Comment: ya i did small change that u suggest, i got it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This won't copy a C string:

```
m[lcounter]=item;
```

Instead, use:

```
strcpy(m[lcounter], item);
```